# passing map between packages in golang

Tags: go

In golang, I know that `map` is passed between functions in the form of reference, but I encountered a strange situation today. The running result of the code is not what I imagined. I simplified it into the following lines of code.

```
.
├── go.mod
├── main.go
├── packageA
│   └── a.go
└── packageB
    └── b.go
```

main.go file

```golang
package main

import (
    "gostudy/packageA"
    "gostudy/packageB"
)

func main() {
    packageB.UseMap(packageA.M, packageA.InitMap)
}
```

a.go

```golang
package packageA

var M map[string]string

func InitMap() {
    M = make(map[string]string)
    M["hello"] = "go"
}
```

b.go

```golang
package packageB

import "fmt"

func UseMap(m map[string]string, callback func()) {
    callback()
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

As you can see, there is only one variable globally declared in the `a.go` file. I thought the above program should output `map[hello:go]`, but it actually outputs an empty `map[]`. I'm very confused about this and hope to get an answer.

Comment: I think you accidentally posted the content of `a.go` in packageB section of your question

Comment: Aha, indeed. Corrected.

Comment: Packages have nothing to do with this behaviour. Same behaviour in a single package: https://go.dev/play/p/_N430ZQxmf_c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the old value of the map as a parameter, before you invoke the function to replace it with a new version of the map.

Let's say `packageA.M` contains the value `map[string]string{"foo": "bar"}`.  The `main()` function reads the variable and gets a reference to this map, and passes it and the function to `packageB.UseMap()`.

Inside `packageB.UseMap()`, your code calls `packageA.InitMap()` via the callback.  This does not modify the existing map; instead, it creates a new map, assigns it to the global variable, and populates it.  Anything that had a copy of the old map is unaffected, and the code you show doesn't re-read the value of `packageA.M`.

I'd recommend dispensing with the global variable entirely: it can make the code hard to test and there are potential problems once you start using goroutines.  Just have your setup function return the new map.

```golang
package packageA

func InitMap() map[string]string {
        return map[string]string{"hello": "go"}
}
```

```golang
package packageB

func UseMap(callback func() map[string]string) {
        m := callback()
        fmt.Println(m)
}
```

```golang
package main

import "packageA"
import "packageB"

func main() {
        packageB.UseMap(packageA.InitMap)
}
```

Comment: Sincerely thank you for your answer, I immediately understood that the problem was that I was confusing references before `new` and references after `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note to the accepted anwer, if you take a look at this:

```golang
// ...
import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

// ... other functions
// I defined all of the functions in a single paackage, so I can access them both here
func UseMap(m map[string]string, callback func()) {
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(m).Pointer() == reflect.ValueOf(M).Pointer()) // prints true, they have the same reference
    callback() 
    // inside callback, M global variable takes a whole new reference
    // when "M = make(...)"
    // and then => 
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(m).Pointer() == reflect.ValueOf(M).Pointer()) // prints false
}
```

If you want to avoid this without changing your apis, you can do this in your package A:

```golang
package packageA

var M map[string]string = make(map[string]string)

func InitMap() {
    M["hello"] = "go"
}
```